npmlibpublish 429 to many requests when using publish function
I am trying to automaticly publish my package to npm using the npmlibpublish JavaScript SDK. Here is my code:
const path = "dist";
    const manifest = await pacote.manifest(path);
    const tarData = await pacote.tarball(path);

    // @ts-ignore
    await publish(manifest, tarData, {
      npmVersion: `universal-fs@${currentVersion}`,
      token: process.env.NPM_TOKEN,
      defaultTag: baseBranch === "main" ? "latest" : "canary",
    });

This code will end up in ci. All of the env is correct as well as the manifest and tarball. However, when I run the code I get an error:
429 Too Many Requests - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/dist

{
  headers: [Object: null prototype] {
    date: [ 'Tue, 17 Sep 2024 01:46:11 GMT' ],
    'content-type': [ 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' ],
    'content-length': [ '5399' ],
    connection: [ 'keep-alive' ],
    'retry-after': [ '3600' ],
    'x-frame-options': [ 'SAMEORIGIN' ],
    'referrer-policy': [ 'same-origin' ],
    'cache-control': [
      'private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'
    ],
    expires: [ 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT' ],
    vary: [ 'Accept-Encoding' ],
    server: [ 'cloudflare' ],
    'cf-ray': [ '8c456bccdd722b8e-LAX' ],
    'x-fetch-attempts': [ '1' ]
  },
  statusCode: 429,
  code: 'E429',
  method: 'PUT',
  uri: 'https://registry.npmjs.org/dist',
  body: Buffer(5399) [Uint8Array] [
     60,  33,  68,  79,  67,  84,  89,  80,  69,  32, 104, 116,
    109, 108,  62,  10,  60,  33,  45,  45,  91, 105, 102,  32,
    108, 116,  32,  73,  69,  32,  55,  93,  62,  32,  60, 104,
    116, 109, 108,  32,  99, 108,  97, 115, 115,  61,  34, 110,
    111,  45, 106, 115,  32, 105, 101,  54,  32, 111, 108, 100,
    105, 101,  34,  32, 108,  97, 110, 103,  61,  34, 101, 110,
     45,  85,  83,  34,  62,  32,  60,  33,  91, 101, 110, 100,
    105, 102,  93,  45,  45,  62,  10,  60,  33,  45,  45,  91,
    105, 102,  32,  73,
    ... 5299 more items
  ],
  pkgid: 'dist@0.1.2'
}

Something that stood out to my was it was trying to publish to a package called dist as seen in pkgid: 'dist@0.1.2'. However, my package is called universal-fs and I am am publishing from the directory dist.
##Edit:
When I print the manifest I get the following:
{
  name: 'dist',
  version: '0.1.2',
  dependencies: { 'uglify-js': '~1.3.4', filesize: '~1.6.6', optimist: '~0.3.5' },
  devDependencies: { mocha: '*' },
  bin: { dist: 'bin/dist.js' },
  dist: {
    shasum: '8898629cc251297e36d1354a9a9598619aba5b1a',
    tarball: 'https://registry.npmjs.org/dist/-/dist-0.1.2.tgz',
    integrity: 'sha512-TmsZfJybRs3IZC8SL/rLU3KYanR31BNPlCutao8MpmiN6S47WN2eEBNSdSafi0cQtdMAixgNXfrqZyuqkz/sOQ==',
    signatures: [ [Object] ]
  },
  _id: 'dist@0.1.2',
  _resolved: 'https://registry.npmjs.org/dist/-/dist-0.1.2.tgz',
  _from: 'dist@*',
  _integrity: 'sha512-TmsZfJybRs3IZC8SL/rLU3KYanR31BNPlCutao8MpmiN6S47WN2eEBNSdSafi0cQtdMAixgNXfrqZyuqkz/sOQ==',
  _signatures: [
    {
      keyid: 'SHA256:jl3bwswu80PjjokCgh0o2w5c2U4LhQAE57gj9cz1kzA',
      sig: 'MEYCIQCsoQHNBg47DoQcIY8LncC/cDOdlO6sdoLGG+j9AH4RtwIhAKKtMyffchsGWccAjrR/l/flTIYsqOLXTTKKZ6BlcGV9'
    }
  ]
}

I have 2fa enabled on my account. name is also defined in my package.json. Why is it trying to publish to dist@0.1.2 and why the 429 status code. How can I fix this?

After some debugging I think this is a bug with npmlibpublish. I have opened an issue here
